# Find $(x,y)$ pairs that satisfy $(x^3+y^2+2)^2 \le 7y^2 +2x^3(y^2+y+2)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Find $(x,y) \in \mathbf{R}$ pairs that satisfy:

$$(x^3+y^2+2)^2 \le 7y^2 +2x^3(y^2+y+2)$$

Comment: well, since $(x^3+y^2+2)^2 \geq 7y^2 +2x^3(y^2+y+2)...................$  Put it all on one side and complete some squares

Comment: You can compute the left minus right terms function and made a minima(um) analysis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expand and bring everything to the left side:

$x^6 -2x^3y+y^4+4-3y^2 \le 0$

Completing the square by add/substracting $y^2$:

$x^6 -2x^3y +y^2  +y^4+4-3y^2- y^2 \le 0$

$(x^3-y)^2 + y^4 -4y^2+4 \le 0 $

$(x^3-y)^2  + (y^2-2)^2 \le 0$

This is true when $x^3-y =0$ and $y^2-2=0$.

Solve the system yields $(\sqrt[6]{2},\sqrt{2})$ and $(-\sqrt[6]{2},-\sqrt{2})$